# Javascript Game Betting

Tags: javascript, html, css

Simple game just figuring out code for the player bank 

 The HTML/CSS is:

`<textarea id="betAmount" class="dice"></textarea>
    <div id="bank" class="dice"></div><p>Bank</p>
    <button onclick="Plant()">Plant!</button>`

The JavaScript is

```
function Plant(){
var betAmount = document.getElementById("betAmount").value;
var bank = document.getElementById("bank").value;
document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML = bank - betAmount;
}
```

Ive also tried passing the code through another variable but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: `div` elements dont have a `value` property - they have `innerHTML` or `innerText`

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: do you have a question about this? is the error on the 2nd line of the function causing it to fail? are you getting `NaN` console errors?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty confusing, but apparently you're trying to remove the bet's value in the bank. So I'll try to help you.

Your code's problem is: `div` does not have value, so you're getting an `undefined` in the second line and, in consequence, a `NaN` as a result.

My suggestion is: change your `div` for a `span` (do not use `div` to hold values) and look for the `innerText` to make it work.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="betAmount" class="dice" />
<p>Bank value:<span id="bank" class="dice">15</span></p>
<button onclick="Plant()">Plant!</button>
```

JS:

```
function Plant() {
    var betAmount = document.getElementById("betAmount").value;
    var bank = document.getElementById("bank").innerText;
    document.getElementById('bank').innerText = bank - betAmount;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2ut401g/

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks heaps! I looked ended up changing the html slightly and then came up with the solution above

Comment: Well, your solution certainly works, but do you think keep the bank value in a textarea (where users can make changes) a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution by changing the HTML slightly to

```
<textarea id="betAmount" class="dice"></textarea>
<textarea id="bank" class="dice">50000</textarea>
```

and then the JS to

```
bank.value = bank.value - betAmount;
```

Thanks for the replies